# How to optimize Clip Path with gif for website

Tags: optimization, video, gif, lighthouse, clip-path

I have created a clip-path with an animated gif in the background like here in Zach Sauciers clip path experiments: https://zachsaucier.com/

This is supposed to be my intro page. From there I can link to the next pages.

Now the gif is just too big (after sending it through online GIF optimizer ezgif.com about 6MB) and the performance in Lighthouse is really bad.

What would you recommend how to optimize the gif best or are there better ways to implement video in a customized clip-path shape?

Or are there even modern ways to create a heart shape with video in it?

I would be happy to hear what you think?